# how to set Android check box border color dark on white background

Tags: android, html, android-studio

i have checkbox under white background , but it is not visible on bare eyes, and i  have searched over SO and learnt that we have to customize checkboxs border to get darker and see by a human eye. But i wanna know is there any possibility any android base api provide any border color property so that i can set to border possibly "Black" and border width thicker as we do in html.

[image is here](http://pho.to/9YuOr)

my check box code

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check_box"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/check_box_width"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:width="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background property of your checkbox to a shape defined as so:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

   <stroke android:width="10px" android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
android:buttonTint="your color_code"
```

Comment: tint will change the checkbox color.